# keep order of delivery after requeue

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm developing an application for messaging using Rabbit MQ. I use explicit ACK:

```
model.BasicConsume(queueName,false, consumer);
```

and do ACK after processing message:

```
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
                {
                    try
                    {                        
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);

                        Logger.Info($"DeliveryTag={ea.DeliveryTag}, message={message}");

                        ((EventingBasicConsumer)ch).Model.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                };
```

The problem is when there is an error of processing a message and Rabbit doesn't receive ACK, it *returns the message to the queue in* **different order**.

Fore example there are messages M1, M2, M3, M4.

If M2 was returned to queue, it will be M3, M4, M2.

Is there any way to **keep the order of delivery**?

P.S. I have only one consumer and RabbitMQ 3.6.6, but I still have problem of reordering.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is answered [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html), under *Message ordering guarantees*. I'll just quote

> Messages can be returned to the queue using AMQP methods that feature
>   a requeue parameter (basic.recover, basic.reject and basic.nack), or
>   due to a channel closing while holding unacknowledged messages. Any of
>   these scenarios caused messages to be requeued at the back of the
>   queue for RabbitMQ releases earlier than 2.7.0. From RabbitMQ release
>   2.7.0, messages are always held in the queue in publication order, **even in the presence of requeueing or channel closure**.
>
> With release 2.7.0 and later it is still possible **for individual
>   consumers** to observe messages out of order if the queue has multiple
>   subscribers. This is due to the actions of other subscribers who may
>   requeue messages. From the perspective of the queue the messages are
>   always held in the publication order.

Comment: Yes, and as i wrote: "I have only one consumer and RabbitMQ 3.6.6, but i still have problem of reordering"

Comment: did you get this resolved? we have the same issue. We want a failed message to keep hitting the front of the queue preventing others being processed until that one is resolved